# jssor Slider sliding behavior

Tags: slideshow, jssor

just playing around with the Jssor Slider http://www.jssor.com/ and so far it looks great!

The only concern that I have is that when you tab between for example tab 1 and tab 4, it slides through tab 2 and 3 also. The behavior that I would like is that it slides straight into which ever tab clicked. (ie. 1-4, but not 2-3 also)

Can anyone tell me if there is built in setting or a work around?

Thanks
Decbrad

Comment: Thanks for your concern. There is no option to do this job at the moment.

Comment: okay! Thanks for replying! Great job!